# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

152 |     const jobs = !!((_a = resume.profession) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.length) ?
153 |         `CARGOS OCUPADOS: ${convertArrayToText(professionDescription(resume))}.  enter code here 154 |   TEMPO DE EXPERIÊNCIA PROFISSIONAL TOTAL:  ${literalTime(normalizedWorTime(resume))}.`  : "";

> 155 |     const languages = !!resume.language.length ? `IDIOMAS: ${convertArrayToText(getLanguageText(resume))}.` : "";
> 156 |     const additional = `PUBLICAÇÕES: ${publicationsText(resume)}. PREMIAÇÕES: ${awardsText(resume)}`;
> 157 |     return education + jobs + languages + additional;
> 158 | }

I have this error in my code, it came up suddenly, I've searched several forums but found nothing relevant.

Within Visual Studio Code, it gives the following error:
"Could not open utils.js in the editor."

When running on Windows, file names are checked against a whitelist to protect against remote code execution attacks. File names may consist only of alphanumeric characters (all languages), periods, dashes,
slashes, and underscores."

```js
 152 |     const jobs = !!((_a = resume.profession) === null || _a === void 0 ? void 0 : _a.length) ?
  153 |         `CARGOS OCUPADOS: ${convertArrayToText(professionDescription(resume))}. 
  154 |   TEMPO DE EXPERIÊNCIA PROFISSIONAL TOTAL:  ${literalTime(normalizedWorTime(resume))}. ` : "";
> 155 |     const languages = !!resume.language.length ? ` IDIOMAS: ${convertArrayToText(getLanguageText(resume))}. ` : "";
  156 |     const additional = `PUBLICAÇÕES: ${publicationsText(resume)}. PREMIAÇÕES: ${awardsText(resume)}`;
  157 |     return education + jobs + languages + additional;
  158 | }
```

Comment: As the error says it can not read the property `length`, and that is because `null`  does not have the property `length`. The problem is that `resume.language` is `null`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `!!resume.language.length` is failing because the `language` property is `null`. You could try [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
const resume = {language: null};
const languages = !!resume.language?.length;

console.log(languages);
```